# Stripping chars from a String with java.regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String str, I want to strip off all the following special characters {}- using Java.regex and replaceAll().

I would do like that:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\{\\}\\-]","");
```

but it doesn't strip what I ask for. Why?

Comment: how your input string looks like? Note that strings are immutable in java, you need to assign the result back to another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s are immutable in Java, meaning `str` won't be modified by calling `replaceAll`. You need to re-assign the new value to the string:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\{\\}\\-]","");
```

Also escaping the curly braces is not needed within character classes:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[{}-]","");
```

Comment: more simpler `str.replaceAll("[{}-]","");`